# Presenting UIActivityViewController casue screen/ui freeze

Tags: ios, swift

I try to present UIActivityViewController to my app users but when I do my app sometimes, not always but often, freeze. What I mean is that activity view is on screen but do not respond to user interaction at all. You can't scroll available items, you cannot select any activity item, you cannot click Cancel etc
The way I invoke it is very simple and basic:

```
func presentSystemShareNotification(notification : Notification) {
    if let vURL = notification.userInfo?["videoURL"] {
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [vURL], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.airDrop]

        naviController.topViewController?.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {() in
            print("done presenting")
        })
    }        
}
```

When ui freezed completion handler is not called. But app itself works, timers are called, ui manipulation like view alpha decrese works and you can see view dim. Any ideas or at least tips what could cause this behavior? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what does notification?["videoURL"] do?. I assume its a network call. If so, you may need to do it first, then pass it into this notification as you are most likely blocking the main thread which will freeze the UI.

Comment: Notification comes from a process that creates video and stores it locally on phone. Becasue it's an asynchronous process it broadcasts notification when file ready to use. Notification is posted in the main thread.  When file is already there notification is posted too but the whole video creation process is skipped. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Did you manage to come up with a solution? I have a similar issue where if I am sharing something on, for example, slack, scrolling and selection and whatnot doesn't work until the sharing is completed.